# how to get proper google_appengine sdk zip?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to download a google appengine sdk to deploy my app via CI.

I used the url: https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.17.zip

But, they changed URL to
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/deprecated/1917/google_appengine_1.9.17.zip
and I cannot access to it (got forbidden).

Google Console URL here:
https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/deprecated/1917/
, but it requires a google credential. It doesn't seems to fit for automation.

Using *current* featured one is fine for a while, but it seems they will move to deprecated and my CI is going to get failed...

Current featured one is here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.18.zip

It's nice that we have a permanent latest sdk URL or versioned ones.

Answer (score 0):

I created a redirect link:

```
$ curl -w "%{redirect_url}" http://gyamp.com/hiroshi/google_appengine_zip
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.18.zip
```